# Differential of $\arccos(\sin x)$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

By the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos(\sin x) = \cos x \;\cdot\; \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x)^2}} = \frac{-\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos^2x}} = -1$$

Without assuming the differential of $\arccos(x)$, one can also let $y = \arccos(\sin x)$ and then differentiate $\cos y = \sin x$ implicitly to eventually reach the same result.

And yet,
$$ \int -1 \;dx = -x + c $$

Does this mean that $\arccos(\sin x)$ can be expressed in the form $-x + c$? If so, what is the value of $c$ and how can this be proven? If not, where is the flaw in my logic above?

Comment: You should formulate the query in a proper mathematical fashion. Define the domains and codomains of all functions involved.

Comment: It should be $\frac{-\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos^2 x}}=\frac{-\cos x}{|\cos x|}=-\text{sgn}(\cos x)$. And the derivative does not exist when $x=\pi/2+\pi n$

Comment: $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = |\cos x|$ so your derivative should be $\pm 1$ depending on the value of $x.$  And $\arccos (\sin x) = \pm x + C$ which it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\arccos (\sin(x))\right]=\frac{-\cos(x)}{|\cos(x)|}=\begin{cases}-1\qquad\text{if $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\pm 2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}\pm 2k\pi\right)$}\\1\qquad~~~\text{if $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm 2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\pm 2k\pi\right)$}\end{cases}$$
and from this we can show that $\arccos (\sin(x))$ is not a linear function, but rather a piecewise "zig-zag" function (I recommend graphing the function).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, thank you. That's my bad: I wasn't really thinking and I for some reason thought $\cos(x)>0$ when $x>0$ and $\cos(x)<0$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw a right triangle with angle $x$, and see that $\arccos(\sin x)=\frac\pi2-x$ (for $0\leq x\leq\frac\pi2$).

Comment: That's only true for some $x$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Added conditions.

Comment: It's actually true in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But drawing a right triangle doesn't prove that without being careful about signs.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sqrt{\cos^2 x}=\vert\cos x\vert=\left\{\begin{array}\\\cos x \;\text{if}\; x\in[-\frac\pi2+2k\pi,\frac\pi2+2k\pi]\\-\cos x \;\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$
And by periodicity it suffices to find the expression of $\arccos(\sin x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x = \cos (\frac \pi2 - x)\\
\arccos (\sin x) = \arccos (\cos (\frac \pi2 - x)) = \frac {\pi}{2} - x$

Or at least it does for the correct intervals of $x.$

Since $\sin x$ is perodic, and $\arccos x$ is a 1-1 function

$\arccos (\sin x)$ is a triangle wave.